# Extract key phrases from a single document

Tags: nlp

I need to extract relevant key phrases from a single document. Since I don't have a lot of documents, TF-IDF doesn't really work.

Currently I'm using TextRank. It produces okay-ish result - some really good phrases along with a lot of garbage.

Is there a better algorithm to use for this? Can anyone give me a rundown of available options?

**Real-world use case**: I'm developing a help desk app that comes with Knowledge Base (a bunch of articles, think of it as FAQ). When a user writes a new support ticket I want to extract key phrases and find the most relevant KB articles. Overall there is not enough data to train a model. I need to compare sets of key phrases I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A related keyword to your case can be **Single Document Keyword Extraction**. A good paper about this is:

> We present a new keyword extraction algorithm that
>   applies to a single document without using a corpus.
>   Frequent terms are extracted first, then a set of cooccurrence
>   between each term and the frequent terms,
>   i.e., occurrences in the same sentences, is generated.
>   **Co-occurrence distribution shows importance of a term
>   in the document as follows. If probability distribution** of
>   co-occurrence between term a and the frequent terms is
>   biased to a particular subset of frequent terms, then term
>   a is likely to be a keyword. The degree of biases of distribution
>   is measured by the $\chi^2$-measure. Our algorithm
>   shows comparable performance to tfidf without using a
>   corpus.

You can find the paper [here](https://ocs.aaai.org/Papers/FLAIRS/2003/Flairs03-076.pdf).

In sum, this paper gives a rank on keywords based on the defined $\chi^2$-measure.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there are any Python implementations? I don't think I'm smart enough to do it myself.

Comment: @MaxAlFarakh https://www.airpair.com/nlp/keyword-extraction-tutorial

Comment: @trollster I tried RAKE. Did not produce good results. I'll look into it again.